# Чи існує український відповідник слова "disclaimer"?

Tags: from-english, переклад

Сьогодні досить поширеними є так звані `дисклеймери`, тобто письмова відмова від відповідальності за дії, вчинені особою, ознайомленою з цією заявою, або ж іншими особами. Наприклад, видання «Українська правда» часто [підписує](http://www.epravda.com.ua/columns/2017/02/13/620639/) авторські статті:

> Колонка є видом матеріалу, який відображає винятково точку зору
>   автора. Вона не претендує на об'єктивність та всебічність висвітлення
>   теми, про яку йдеться. Точка зору редакції може не збігатися з точкою зору автора. Редакція
>   не відповідає за достовірність та тлумачення наведеної інформації і
>   виконує винятково роль носія.

Чи є український (нетранслітерований) відповідник даного слова?

Answer (score 14):

Це [запозичене слово](http://slovnenya.com/dictionary/disclaimer), яке має [кілька](http://uk.dictionarist.com/%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%96%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B0/disclaimer) відповідностей:

1. відказ, відмова, відмовлення, відречення, зречення, самопожертва
2. відречення, заперечення, заперечування
3. дезавуювання
4. [інший варіант](https://uk.glosbe.com/en/uk/disclaimer): *застереження*

В той же час *disclaimed* [перекладається](http://slovnenya.com/dictionary/disclaimed) як *заперечений*.

Українська Вікі [використовує](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D1%96%D0%BA%D1%96%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%96%D1%8F:%D0%92%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0_%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B4_%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%96) термін *відмова від відповідальності*, який не потребує додаткового пояснення.

Comment: У юридичному середовищі (а, певно, на нього варто орієнтуватися, оскільки автора запитання цікавить саме юридичний відповідник) найчастіше вживається **застереження**. І я за цей варіант.  [Всеукраїнська громадська організація "Асоціація правників України"](http://uba.ua/ukr/disclaimer/); [openaeuropeancompany.com](http://www.openaeuropeancompany.com/uk/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F/) тощо.